# Error while updating DB2 Database table on AS/400 using Business Objects Data Integrator 11.7

Tags: db2, odbc, driver, ibm-midrange, business-objects

we need to update records in DB2 database table on AS/400 using Business Objects Data Integrator 11.7. Data integrator Designer version is 11.7.3
Drivers installed are iSeries ACCESS ODBC Driver 11.0.2,CLIENT ACCESS ODBC DRIVER 11.0.2

We are able to do the update for a single record, but while doing Bulk Update, we are getting below error message, Can anyone help on this.

```
DBS-070401: ODBC DATA SOURCE <xxxx> Error Message for Operation
<SQLExecute>: <[IBM][iSeries Access ODBC Driver]Driver not capable.>
RUN-051005:
Execution of <Regular Load Operations> for target <XXX_XXXX> failed. Possible causes: (1) Error in the SQL syntax; (2) Database
connection is broken; (3) Database related errors such as transaction log is full, etc.; (4) The user defined in the datastore
has insufficient privileges to execute the SQL. If the error is for preload or postload operation, or if it is for regular load
operation and load triggers are defined, please check the SQL. Otherwise, for (3) and (4), please contact your local DBA.
```

If the select Query for the DI job is filtered for only one record, below update statement is generated and is executed through Data Integrator. In this case, no driver error is displayed.

```
UPDATE TIBCO_STG.PUB_AREA SET ADB_L_DELIVERY = 'C'   WHERE ADB_SEQUENCE = 22849415
```

If the select query is not filtered, below four update SQLs are Generated by the DI Job, Driver error is displayed on this Bulk records update.

```
UPDATE TIBCO_STG.PUB_AREA SET ADB_L_DELIVERY = 'C'   WHERE ADB_SEQUENCE = 22849415 
UPDATE TIBCO_STG.PUB_AREA SET ADB_L_DELIVERY = 'C'   WHERE ADB_SEQUENCE = 22849416 
UPDATE TIBCO_STG.PUB_AREA SET ADB_L_DELIVERY = 'C'   WHERE ADB_SEQUENCE = 22849417 
UPDATE TIBCO_STG.PUB_AREA SET ADB_L_DELIVERY = 'C'   WHERE ADB_SEQUENCE = 22849418
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the statement you're trying to run?

Comment: Have you checked the joblog on the iSeries for the SQL job?

Comment: @Jane Thanks We have checked in the “Job Error Log” in the Data Integrator Manangement Console. Can you please advise how to check the joblog on the iSeries.

Comment: @david.Thanks.Ive updated the question with the example.

Comment: Your bulk update appears to be lots of SQL statements.  with no semi colons, have you tried reformating to put all the sequences in a in clause?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your application logic flow? There may be a better way to approach what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any semicolons between your UPDATE statements.

You may also want to consider other methods.  For example:

```
UPDATE TIBCO_STG.PUB_AREA 
  SET ADB_L_DELIVERY = 'C' 
  WHERE ADB_SEQUENCE in (22849415, 22849416, 22849417, 22849418)
```

or

```
UPDATE TIBCO_STG.PUB_AREA 
  SET ADB_L_DELIVERY = 'C' 
  WHERE ADB_SEQUENCE in (select seq from someFullSelectOrWorkFile)
```

If there is some way to code the WHERE condition as a fullSelect, you would be able to accomplish this in a single SQL statement.  Set-at-a-time processing is far more efficient than row-at-a-time.

Comment: @ Warren..Thanks Yes. You are correct, that there is no semicolons in the update statement.These sqls are written on the file (Overflow) set by the DI JOB while running the job.
these sqls does not have semicolon by default, we use this over flow file option to check the sql generated by DI job is correct or not.

As we are getting a driver error, is there any incompatibility of the ODBC Drivers used (iSeries ACCESS ODBC Driver 11.0.2,CLIENT ACCESS ODBC DRIVER 11.0.2) 
for the DI verson (Business Objects Data Integrator 11.7. Data integrator Designer version is 11.7.3)

Comment: @JaneT . Thanks Jane, Records will be reading sequentially from source and will be updating the target as multiple sql requests.

Answer (score 2):

Your driver would be part of IBM i Access for Windows.  To make sure you have the latest version, open System i Navigator, and look under Help / About.  The version shown there should be at least as high or higher than the release of the IBM i OS on your server.  A higher version of IBM i Access driver should support at least 2 prior releases of the server OS.  See this [compatibility page](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/resources/connections.html) if you need more details.

Currently, the most recent release is 7.1 both for IBM i, and for IBM Access for Windows.

Next, always be sure that you have the [latest service pack](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/windows_sp.html) installed.